# why doesnt my Javascript code pass unit test case in chai

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

Pyramid of star code in java script failed test case

My output doesn't match with the test case written in Mocha. Probably issue with \n character.

```
const buildPyramid = (num) => {
  var stars = '';
  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    for (var k = 1; k <= num - i + 1; k++) {
      stars += ' ';
    }
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      stars += '* ';
    }
    console.log(stars + '\n');
    stars = '';
  }


};
```

---

**my Test case :**

```
const chai = require('chai');
const expect = chai.expect;
const pyramid = require('../solutions/q1_pyramid_of_stars.js');

describe('Testing - pyramid_of_stars', () => {
  it('module return type test case', (done) => {
    expect(typeof pyramid).to.deep.equal('function');
    done();
  });

  it('positive test case for odd count of height', (done) => {
    expect(pyramid(5)).equal(
      '     *  \n    * *  \n   * * *  \n  * * * *  \n * * * * *  \n');
    done();
  });

  it('positive test case for even count of height', (done) => {
    expect(pyramid(6)).equal(
      '      *  \n     * *  \n    * * *  \n   * * * *  \n  * * * * *  \n * * * * * *  \n');
    done();
  });

  it('negative test case', (done) => {
    expect(pyramid('invalid value')).to.deep.equal('');
    done();
  });
});
```

error: 1) Testing - pyramid_of_stars
       positive test case for odd count of height:
     AssertionError: expected undefined to equal '     *  \n    * *  \n   * * *  \n  * * * *  \n * * * * *  \n'
      at Context.it (test\q1_pyramid_of_stars.spec.js:12:22)

2) Testing - pyramid_of_stars
       positive test case for even count of height:
     AssertionError: expected undefined to equal '      *  \n     * *  \n    * * *  \n   * * * *  \n  * * * * *  \n * * * * * *  \n'
      at Context.it (test\q1_pyramid_of_stars.spec.js:18:22)

3) Testing - pyramid_of_stars
       negative test case:
     AssertionError: expected undefined to deeply equal ''
      at Context.it (test\q1_pyramid_of_stars.spec.js:24:44)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working properly and so are your tests. The problem here is that your `buildPyramid` function **always returns undefined** because you're just using `console.log` to output the result.

Try changing it to something like this

```
const buildPyramid = num => {
  var stars = '';
  for (var i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    for (var k = 1; k <= num - i + 1; k++) {
      stars += ' ';
    }
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      stars += '* ';
    }
    stars = stars + '\n';
  }
  return stars;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. It works absolutely fine now.